# Loading XAML files at runtime cannot find namespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to load styles from an external uncompiled XAML file in the folder of the executable for easy theming. Unfortunately, I have not been able to do so since every custom namespace used in the XAML file throws an exception. The same file does load if i use Application.LoadComponent but I want it to be externally loaded.

Here is the method I use to load the xaml file:

```
    void LoadThemeExternal(string name)
    {
        var path = "Themes/" + name + ".xaml";
        ResourceDictionary resourceDict;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            resourceDict = (ResourceDictionary)XamlReader.Load(fs); // This line throws an exception.
        Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDict);
    }
```

and here is the XAML file I have created which I cannot load using this method:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Effects="clr-namespace:CleverDock.Effects" xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:CleverDock.Controls">
    <Style TargetType="Image" x:Key="IconImageStyle">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
        <Setter Property="Image.Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Effects:BrightnessEffect Brightness="0"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The exception happens at XamlReader.Load(fs)

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Cannot create unknown type '{clr-namespace:CleverDock.Effects}BrightnessEffect'.' Line number '12' and line position '18'.
```

The effect that it is trying to load is a custom ShaderEffect which works fine when the XAML is loaded within a compiled resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake! I needed to specify the **;assembly=CleverDock** in the ResourceDictionary like so:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Effects="clr-namespace:CleverDock.Effects;assembly=CleverDock">
```

Then the Xaml loads without problems